# ads are not appearing in my app (using libgdx)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I am creating a game using libgdx, i finished the coding and everything is working
but when i implement the ad it doesnt appear

This is my MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import com.pixelstudioz.RevengeOfTheTunnels.ROTTGame;

public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication{



 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = false;
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameViewParams =
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //gameViewParams.bottomMargin = 150;
        requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
        View gameView = initializeForView(new ROTTGame(), cfg);
        layout.addView(gameView, gameViewParams);

        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdUnitId("YOUR ADMOB AD ID");
        //adView.setAdUnitId("app-id");
        adView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.BANNER);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

        layout.addView(adView, adParams);

        com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest request = new          com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
        .build();
        adView.loadAd(request);
        setContentView(layout);



        initialize(new ROTTGame(), cfg);
    }
}
```

and this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
package="com.package.appname"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.ads.GoogleAdsSampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pixelstudioz.RevengeOfTheTunnels.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>
```

and this is my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>
<com.google.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="unitid"
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

PLEASE HELP
DO i  need the app id first??? like from admob?? or what??
anw check the code, and thanksss

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are initializing your Game twice...

First, you are using the `intitializeForView()` method to get back the main window view that is used and which contains the OpenGL Window your libgdx stuff runs in.

This way, by the way, you will never need the `layout.xml`... Libgdx creates a layout Object (the `gameView` you get back from `initializeForView()`. So although the layout.xml is present, it's never actually used, so it also doesn't matter if you put an adview in there.

And at the bottom of your `onCreate()` you are calling `initialize(new ROTTGame(), cfg);` again, creating a second game view with opengl window and a new instance of your game. And this will override the first instance you have created and to which you have added your `AdView` instance.

So if you remove that last line, it should work.

Nevertheless, you will still need to input all necessary data from your AdMob account, meaning your ID etc and ideally adding a test device. Before adding the ID, you most likely won't get any ads from AdMob and ergo won't get anything to show...

Hope it helps...

Comment: so all I need to do is to remove the initialize(new ROTTGame(), cfg) or the initializeForView()

Comment: what i need to do after that to show the ad??thank you in return

Comment: And do i need to have the app id to display the ad?

Comment: Right, you need to remove `initialize(new ROTTGame(), cfg);`... The other code on initializing the views looks ok. You also need to add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> ` to your manifest so that your app has internet access and can fetch the ads.

Comment: If tried what u have said, and i added the app id, and still now ad appearing....what do u need to see so u could help?

Comment: please help, i removed the initialize(new ROTTGame(), cfg); and i added the permission and used the app id, but now im testing the app and its crashing when i press it...whats the problem??